# How to style my Plotly Dash app using bootstrap?

Tags: python, css, plotly, plotly-dash

Here is my code. 
I am trying to align the two charts on the side of each other.

What is the simplest way to do it?

```
    ########### Display the chart
    app = dash.Dash()
    server = app.server

    app.layout = html.Div(style={'backgroundColor': '#000000'},children=[
        html.H1('Indicator'),
        dcc.Graph(
            id='Teste1',
            figure=client_relation
        ),

        dcc.Graph(
            id='Test2',
            figure=beer_fig
        ),


        ]
    )

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        app.run_server()
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using this code. Add style as  'inline-block' to your code for both graphs to be  in line.
Include both  graphs in one html block.

```
dcc.Graph(id='my_graph1',style={'width':1000, 'display': 'inline-block'},
        figure=go.Figure(
            data =[trace1, trace2],
            layout = go.Layout(
            title=' nifty',

            xaxis=dict(
                #domain=[0.03, 0.9]
                title='Date',
            ),
            yaxis=dict(
                title='Nifty',
                side='right',
            ), 
        ),

dcc.Graph(id='Pie',style={'width': 500, 'display': 'inline-block'},
),

html.Hr(),
```

Hope you can take this and modify.